# Url foundation submenu not directing to the page

Tags: php, css, laravel, zurb-foundation, laravel-9

hi i have this foundation top-bar in my laravel app

I have issue with the submenu section but all the  in the submenu are not working if i remove them from the submenu they are working and redirecting to the good page

```
<div class="top-bar" id="responsive-menu">
    <div class="top-bar-left">
        <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
            <li class="menu-text">Lison Admin</li>
            <li><a href="{{ url('orders') }}">Commandes</a></li>
            <li class="has-submenu">
                <a href="#0">Profils - Filtres </a>
                <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu>
                    <li><a href="{{ url('profils') }}">Profils</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{ url('orders') }}">Filtres</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#0">Three</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```